# Setting binding on a WPF label in codebehind not working due to ContentProperty not being recognised

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have the following method in my View;

```
Label GetSummaryLabel(Panel panel, ServiceChargeType type)
{
    var chargeTextbox = panel.Children[1];

    var summarybinding = new Binding { Source = chargeTextbox, Path = new PropertyPath("Text") };
    var summaryLabel = new Label();
    summaryLabel.SetBinding(ContentProperty, summarybinding);

    return summaryLabel;
}
```

This works fine, but I want to move this function to a helper class, when I do so I get the following compile error;

"Cannot resolve symbol 'ContentProperty'

Why?

Comment: You might want to use `ContentControl.ContentProperty` when you move this code to a helper class.

Comment: I fixed the problem by changing ContentProperty to ContentControl.ContentProperty but would still like to understand why this was not required in the view codebehind

Comment: Thanks sthotakura, read your comment straight after writing mine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ContentProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentproperty(v=vs.110).aspx) is a `static` member on ContentControl class. When you are in your view (i.e. [UserControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window(v=vs.110).aspx)), you are already in one of the derived classes from `ContentControl` and the `ContentProperty` is available. However, when you move your code to a helper, you need to classify the `ContentProperty` with it's class name.

HTH